# Is there a philosophical framework for deciding on exposing humanity changing technology?

Tags: ethics, free-will, artificial-intelligence, social-ethics, good-and-evil

Let us assume, there is an inventor who thinks he/she is possess a humanity altering technology. For example, an artificial intelligence. He/she is also concerned, with possible adverse effects,  his/her invention may bring. **Is there any existing philosophical framework, our hero may align her/himself with?**

I'm a science fiction writer. In my story, a hero invented/on the brink of inventing, possibly humanity altering technology. Let us assume, artificial intelligence, although – you may assume any other breakthrough, for your own convenience. He/she is considered, with possible adverse effects, his/her invention (should I say, work?) will have, never mind his/her noble intentions. For example, global corporations will seize on academically freely published work, in order to create “spy society”, where nobody is really free, being constantly watched by money hungry corporations, exploiting everything  and everyone – just to make profit. Or (existing?) totalitarian regimes, using unscrupulous robot policemen and ever watching computers, to eliminate political rivals and free will from their countries. Or those computers, might rebel by themselves, aiming at eliminating humanity, seen as threat/competitor – as seen in so many movies. You see, that's why I've chosen artificial intelligence – there is just a great deal of existing stories, which departing points is “AI gone bad”. You may think of any other important invention, through.

I think, there was a man, who contributed greatly to the dream of flying. If I recall correctly, many parts crucial for modern aircraft, were invented/greatly contributed by him. Sadly, he was greatly dishearten, seeing many of his inventions – and aircraft as a whole – put for military use, for indiscriminate killing. One day, seeing aircraft fighting at a distance (for some reason, I recall it be in Brazil), he went inside and committed suicide. As I recall, he cannot bear he contributed for loss of life and destruction. I may be wrong on details, but I  do recall this story from “history channel” program.

Now, we all can offer advise, but that's not why I'm asking that question. I'm sure we all can offer our thoughts, but that would be too opinionated, and therefore – not appropriate for asking here (even irrelevant, all general appeals are equal). Instead, what I'm asking about, it **if there an existing philosophical work, aiming at providing a framework for our hero decision?**

You see, my training is in exact sciences, with somewhat training in philosophy. I'm familiar with many generals concepts, such as Platos' Allegory of the cave (which in turn, may even suggest you should give your invention to humanity, in order to improve people lives) and such. What I'm unfamiliar with, it if there an existing work by somebody, aiming at providing a framework for our hero decision. We all can agree, there are always good and bad consequences for every action. That's great rule of thumb. But when we're down at police precinct, we all be rather giving our testimony for somebody who's there to serve and protect. Not to your “copied from the movies”, corrupt cup. Society I guess, makes the difference. Maybe something else. Maybe somebody already tackled this question, for some reason. Maybe something close. **References for such works, will be greatly appreciated. Explaining the terms of those, even more.**

Comment: Could you please revise the questions title? The question itself is well-writing; the title reads like you explicitly tried to break all the rules of English grammar. It's indecipherable.

Comment: Sure. Changed it.

Comment: This framework is called ethics of technology, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics_of_technology) for an intro, and [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/technology/#EthiSociAspeTech) for a more academic take.

Comment: You might research the history of the origin of species that Darwin withheld before publishing, and the theatre play"Copenhagen" about discussing the impact of atomic bombs before their use in WW2.